# What is the fastest way to travel in Minecraft using non-standard means?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

"Travel" meaning getting roughly 200 meters between two locations in the regular world.
Includes time to prepare expendables and/or eat to get full (but not worrying about damage).  I don't care how much time it takes to build infrastructure in any of this.

"Non Standard" meaning, there *has* to be a faster way than a boat or a minecart or even going to the nether.

"Minecraft" meaning vanilla single player mode.

"Fastest" meaning, m/s numbers please.  Speculative answers such as usually given in these questions (i.e. like this [one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20835/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-travel-long-distances-in-minecraft)) are not what I'm looking for.

Related sub questions might be: How far can you throw an ender pearl, and how long is it in the air (in seconds)?  Are there ways to throw an ender pearl 200 meters?  What speed can you get out of a well built EATS road (in m/s)?  How fast (in m/s) is boat teleporting?  minecart teleporting?  Is there a way to use a TNT cannon that doesn't kill me half the time?

Comment: I assume you want to do this in vanilla single player?

Comment: @uncovery yes!!!

Comment: Is there any reason that the various answers to [What is the fastest way to travel long distances in Minecraft?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20835/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-travel-long-distances-in-minecraft) don't satisfy you?

Comment: The fastest way should be `/tp <player> x y z`, requiring cheats on.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie the reason I added this question, was none of the many variants I saw gave quantitative numbers (i.e. m/s) Lots of speculation as to what's fastest, but no tests.  Didn't want to have to run the tests if the result was already known.

Comment: @John You might want to rewrite this to clearly focus on that in the question. As it reads now, it's not asking for quantitative values from tested methods, so you're just going to gather the same kind of answers (including speculation) as the other question.

Comment: The answer to this question depends on when the reader is looking at it.

Comment: @Userthatisnotauser totally agree.  I've been thinking of writing a much better answer to this question than I've seen to date.  There are a couple of youtubers that do regular speed experiments, that would be worth documenting.

Answer (score 14):

You can boost a thrown Ender Pearl using a TNT cannon. Assuming you've got the trajectory exactly right and have a wall at the destination to stop the pearl, this is basically instantaneous other than the fuse time (4 seconds). Also, in one step you can only travel as far as the chunk load distance, which as far as I've read is 160m (10 chunks), or else the pearl will not land until you move closer. So, **speed: 40 m/s average**, less time to gather resources and place the TNT, and the flight time of the pearl (which will depend on the amount of TNT used and exact trajectory).

If you built a series of redstone-driven TNT magazines wired to operate in sequence and launched pearls perfectly to match them, then you could avoid waiting 4 seconds and move even faster.

Comment: You can double this by using the nether and some portals.

Answer (score 6):

In vanilla, single-player minecraft, the fastest way to travel any distance is to use command blocks to set up teleports.  These will send you any distance in any direction instantly.

While command blocks *are* vanilla, they are not possible to get in a non-cheat-enabled game.  You need to be in creative gamemode and have access to the /give command to obtain them without mods.  If your world has cheats enabled or you are willing to use an external program to assist in getting the command blocks set up, then they will work just fine in vanilla from then on.

To get the command block and give yourself the ability to set it up, enter the following in chat:

```
/gamemode creative @p
/give @p 137
```

Place the command blocks where you want them and use them to teleport near each other.  For example, if you have one (which I'll call A) at (x,y,z)=(0,5,0) and the other at (x,y,z)=(200,5,0) (which I'll call B,) then right click on command block A and type

```
 tp @p 200 5 5
```

into the command field.  Similarly, in command block B's field, use

```
 tp @p 0 5 5
```

Note that in each case, I've put the teleport "landing zone" +5 Z-blocks from the other command block.  Now place a stone pressure plate on top of each and step on it.  You'll be instantly sent to the vicinity of the other.

To return to survival mode, use:

```
 /gamemode survival @p
```

I've created a small (~300k) [demo map](http://www.minecraftworldmap.com/worlds/iDMTK) demonstrating this that you can try out in vanilla Minecraft 1.4.7.

Comment: Also a great answer, however the first answer works without 3rd party programs or cheats, so that's the better answer in my opinion, and the votes show it as well as of NOW, perhaps the community will swing your way.

Answer (score 2):

This YouTuber is going 47.4 blocks per second. I've tried it myself too, works okay. I'm getting 43.1 b/s.

In this video he placed Minecarts every 3 blocks to be able to spam right-click, teleporting to the next minecart in front of him every right-click. That way, by spamming rightclick, he got very fast. 47.4 m/s he got, I am getting to 43.1 b/s.

Comment: Hi @LProd, can you add a description of what's going on to your post? If the video were to go away your answer wouldn't say much at all, and that would be a shame.

Comment: I edited it to clarify it. You're welcome.

Comment: I personally prefer this method over the pearl tossing method.  This method has a lot more flexibility IMHO, and more accuracy.  But, totally understand the communities infatuation with TNT!

Answer (score 0):

Just type in gamemode 3. This is spectator mode. The only thing you can do is fly around and view other mobs and players. Simply go to gamemode 3,(`/gamemode 3`) then use your scroll button, and you can reach amazing speed. You can also fly through blocks. Then switch back to your normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way i know is by a horse. You can get one that runs a 12m/s and use potion of swiftness to go faster and also go through the nether witch brings it up to 120m/s above ground.

Comment: 12 times 8 not times 10. A block in the nether is 8 blocks in the overworld

Answer (score 0):

A lot has changed since any of the answers were given, and some fairly definitive testing was done by Mumbo Jumbo to answer this.  All answers come from his video called, "What's the fastest Way to Travel in Minecraft 1.14?"  With a couple of additions from the wiki.

All speeds are in blocks per second.  None of this takes into account, the ridiculousness that is the scicraft TNT ender pearl cannon, which is some ridiculous speed that I don't remember.

In this list, remember, that the non-water based techniques, can be accomplished in the Nether, and thus can get an 8X speed up.  I'll leave that math up to you, but the winner is clearly Blue Ice Boat for Nether transport.

- 125  -> Riptide 3
- 74   -> Dolphin + Speed 2 potion
- 55   -> Dolphin
- 45   -> Blue Ice Boat
- 45 ish -> spam clicking minecarts as mentioned in the other answer (does this work in 1.14?)
- 33   -> Elytra
- 33   -> Ice Boat
- 19   -> Piston Bolt
- 19-15 -> Various sprint jump methods
- 14    -> Best Possible Horse (without speed)
- 9     -> Average Horse
- 8     -> Minecart
- 6     -> Sprinting

Answer (score -1):

you could just turn on cheats and type

```
/set speed 40
```

you could also type in any other number above 20 and get to 200 meters in a few seconds.

Comment: I do believe this is a command from the SPC (Single Player Commands) mod.

Comment: Which is't up to date I beleve